# Display user inputs in textarea and format as array in database PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, textarea

I've created a custom options page for my WordPress theme and have a textarea for users to add options that will be appended to an array in another file. User input is successfully added to the appropriate location in the database, but it is being stored as a single string. I would like for the user to be able to enter one option on each line and have the inputs saved as an array with each line being saved as an element in the array.

for example:

Textarea user input:

```
'my option1'
'my option2'
'my option3'
```

is stored as:

```
a:1:{s:24:"my_textarea_field_0";s:34:"my option1
my option2
my option3";}
```

I would like for it to be stored as an array: {"my option1", "my option2", "my option3"}

Also, the text entered into the textarea is saved to the database but is not displayed in the textarea after the submit button is pressed. I would like for the user's input the be added to the database as an array and continue to be displayed in the textarea after it has been submitted.

Here is the relevant code:

```
function my_textarea_field_0_render() { 
        $this->$options = get_option('my_settings');
        ?>
        <p style="margin: .25em 0 .5em!important; display: inline-block;">
            <label for="my_settings[my_textarea_field_0]">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
        <textarea cols='145' rows='8' name='my_settings[my_textarea_field_0]'><?php echo $options['my_textarea_field_0'];?></textarea>
        </p>
        <?php
        add_option('my_settings', '$options');
}
```

I've spent a while searching for solutions and tinkering with the code, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

1. To make array from value of textarea, use `explode` function. Maybe this sample code is useful for you.

```php
$arrTextarea = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $valTextarea));
```

2. You should use only `php` code in function.

```php
function my_textarea_field_0_render() { 
    $this->$options = get_option('my_settings');    
    $html = `
        <p style="margin: .25em 0 .5em!important; display: inline-block;">
            <label for="my_settings[my_textarea_field_0]">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea cols='145' rows='8' name='my_settings[my_textarea_field_0]'>` . 
                $options['my_textarea_field_0'] . 
            `</textarea>
        </p>`;
    add_option('my_settings', '$options'); // I didn't understand what is $options.
}
```